# Formatting fzf multi-select output for mpv

Tags: command-line-arguments, fzf, mpv

The following works:

```
# play file1 and then file 2:
mpv "file1" "file 2"

# use fzf to select a file and play that file:
mpv "$(fdfind . /path/to/Music | fzf)"
```

Now `fzf -m` allows for multi-select. However the following doesn't work:

```
mpv "$(fdfind . /path/to/Music | fzf -m)" #select at least 2 files here
```

At first I thought the problem is that `fzf -m` returns the selections separated by newline, such as:

```
file1
file 2
```

So I tried some `sed`/ `awk` stuff:

```
fdfind . /path/to/Music | fzf -m |
    sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' | #double quotes every line
    awk 1 ORS=' ' | #replace newline with ' '
    head -c -1 | #delete the last ' '
```

To format it as:

```
"file1" "file 2"
```

This also doesn't work. So I also tried `kdialog` with the following:

```
mpv "$(kdialog --getopenfilename --multiple /path/to/Music/)" #select at least 2 files here
```

And it doesn't work. However the [kdialog-open-files.lua](https://gist.github.com/ntasos/d1d846abd7d25e4e83a78d22ee067a22) user-script works fine for me!

I think I am making a mistake in how I am passing the arguments to `mpv`, as the following (obviously) works:

```
mpv "$(fdfind . /path/to/Music | fzf)" "$(fdfind . /path/to/Music | fzf)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it from [this stack-overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279693/why-mpv-ls-video-is-not-the-same-as-mpv-video-pls-help-noobie-to):

```
fdfind . Music/ | fzf -m | xargs -d "\n" mpv
```

You can also pass command line arguments to `mpv` this way:

```
fdfind . Music/ | fzf -m | xargs -d "\n" mpv --volume=50 --loop-playlist=inf
```

etc.