# Use fdfind and fzf to open files in mpv

Tags: lua, fzf, mpv

[kdialog-open-files.lua](https://gist.github.com/ntasos/d1d846abd7d25e4e83a78d22ee067a22) and [zenity-open-files.lua](https://github.com/alifarazz/mpv-zenity-open-files/blob/master/zenity-open-files.lua) are two projects that use `KDE KDialog` and `Gnome's zenity` respectively to open files in `mpv`. I wish to do the same using `fdfind` and `fzf`.

As illustrated in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73538150/4949315) the following works and will be our starting point:

```
fdfind . /path/to/Music | fzf -m | xargs -d "\n" mpv
```

We can use the above command to select some files and play them using `mpv`. However we want a dialog to be created for our file selection. To do this, we create a `bash` script `menu_fzf.sh` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
urxvt -name fzf_menu -e bash -c "fzf -m $* < /proc/$$/fd/0 > /proc/$$/fd/1"
```

(`urxvt` is only an example and any other suitable terminal emulator can be used in the above).

Now if we run:

```
fdfind . /path/to/Music | menu_fzf.sh
```

then a new terminal opens that lets you pick multiple files from `/path/to/Music` with `fzf` and will return the selection as output to the calling terminal. So in fact right now we could run the following

```
fdfind . /path/to/Music | menu_fzf.sh | xargs -d "\n" mpv
```

and it will play the selected files in `mpv`. So far so good!

The tricky part now is how to do all the above using `lua` scripts from within `mpv`. By looking at the `kdialog-open-files.lua` or `zenity-open-files.lua` it seems I need to write something like this:

```
utils = require 'mp.utils'

-- TODO: make the following work so that file_select correctly stores
-- the files selected using menu_fzf.sh:
file_select = utils.subprocess({
    args = {'command', 'argument1', 'argument2', 'and so on'},
    cancellable = false,
    })

-- and then the rest of the code from kdialog-open-files.lua
```

However I am finding the [official manual for `utils.subprocess`](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#lua-scripting-utils-subprocess(t)) to be terse and inadequate. I have creatively tried picking `command`, `argument1`, `argument2`, `and so on` in the above, but nothing seems to work!

So I have two questions:

1. Can you (please) complete the above code template into a working solution?
2. Do you know where I can find more information on `utils.subprocess`? Is there a more detailed manual somewhere? Where is the source-code?

**Remark**: As I have never programmed in `lua` before I am struggling with solving question-1 above and will probably continue to struggle even if I had the source code for `utils.subprocess`. So really help with question-1 is of higher priority. But any help with question-2 is also great!

**My failed attempts so far**:

The following will append all files in current directory to playlist:

```
file_select = utils.subprocess({
  args = {'fdfind', '.', directory},
  cancellable = false,
})
```

The following fails:

```
file_select = utils.subprocess({
  args = {'fdfind', '.', directory, '|', 'fzf'},
  cancellable = false,
})
```

with error message:

```
[open_files] [fd error]: Search path '|' is not a directory.
[open_files] [fd error]: Search path 'fzf' is not a directory.
```

The following allows selecting multiple files from `$HOME` directory but (as expected) does not return the selection:

```
file_select = utils.subprocess({
  args = {'urxvt','-e','fzf', '-m'},
  cancellable = false,
})
```

The following doesn't work:

```
file_select = utils.subprocess({
  args = {'urxvt','-e','fzf', '-m', '>', '/proc/$$/fd/1'},
  cancellable = false,
})
```

The following opens up a new dialog with `fzf` but has nothing to select from:

```
file_select = utils.subprocess({
  args = {'menu_fzf.sh'},
  cancellable = false,
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `bash` script `mpv_fzf_menu.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
urxvt -name fzf_menu -e bash -c "fdfind . "$1" | fzf -m > /proc/$$/fd/1"
```

Create a `lua` file `open-files.lua` with the following content:

```
utils = require 'mp.utils'

function select_files_dmenu_fzf()
    if mp.get_property("path") == nill then
        directory = ""
    else
        directory = utils.split_path(utils.join_path(mp.get_property("working-directory"), mp.get_property("path")))
    end
    
    file_select = utils.subprocess({
      args = {'mpv_fzf_menu.sh', directory},
      cancellable = false,
    })
end

function add_files()
   select_files_dmenu_fzf()
   if (file_select.status ~= 0) then return end
   
   local first_file = true
   for filename in string.gmatch(file_select.stdout, '[^\n]+') do
      mp.commandv('loadfile', filename, first_file and 'replace' or 'append')
      first_file = false
   end
end

mp.add_key_binding("Ctrl+f", "add-files-kdialog", add_files)
```

(I am assuming you know what to do next: make the `bash` script executable and put it somewhere where `bash` finds it in its `$PATH`. Put the `lua` script in `.config/mpv/scripts` and everything should work, i.e. - when you press `Ctrl+f` within `mpv` a dialog should open to let you select files).

**Remark**: All the functionalities of `kdialog-open-files.lua` have not been implemented. But the above `lua` script can be easily extended. You can further make things fancy by filtering for files with the specified extension with `fdfind`. And you can also use the `bash` script independent of the `lua` script. If you configure the `--preview` option of `fzf` then you can get a file preview before making selection.